# postgresql store all records/ rows of a record

Tags: postgresql

I can iterate/loop over all rows/ record returned by select statement.

After looping if i check the record it contains the last row only.

I want to have all rows in the record. How to achieve this

Comment: looks like when we loop over it, next row is assigned to record. So that effectively at any point of time record variable has only one row information. Is it correct?

Comment: It sounds like you simply need an array or a collection.

Comment: So need to create an array of record and for every iteration/loop fill the array? So this is correct understanding that when in loop record is filled with next row information. So at any point of time record variable has only 1 row information